# React native signed apk crashed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I followed all the steps which are in the react native docs. I created a signed **apk**, but when I installed it on the device it is crashing.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you follow the below steps :

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android#docsNav

If you still facing issue then try below link :

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/troubleshooting

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your answer, Yes it is right I also tried troubleshooting and then made signed build it. worked for me.